# How to solve a problem using row_number, lag / lead, join SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

In sql, I'm completely new, but I need to solve this problem using only row_number, lag / lead, join. I’ve been struggling with the problem for 2 days and I just can’t solve it correctly.

We have a table with data, you need to get the answer of the following from:

```
 Client 2017-11-01 04:59:07.6140000 2017-11-01 05:06:53.9090000 Agent C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
    Client 2017-11-01 05:07:18.7020000 2017-11-01 05:07:43.1280000 Agent C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
    Client 2017-11-01 05:07:59.5780000 2017-11-01 05:14:12.5870000 Agent C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
    Client 2017-11-01 05:14:56.3690000 2017-11-01 06:06:56.1080000 Agent C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
    Client 2017-11-01 06:21:17.5480000 2017-11-01 06:21:38.4280000 Agent C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
```

It's my code:

```
      if object_id('tempdb..#c1') is not null
          drop table #c1

        create table #c1 (datemessage datetime2 ,id_tasks nvarchar(255),Whowritedmessage nvarchar(255));

        insert into #c1 
        values
        ('2017-11-01 04:59:07.614','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Client'),
        ('2017-11-01 05:05:17.500','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Client'),
        ('2017-11-01 05:06:53.909','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Agent'),
        ('2017-11-01 05:06:53.909','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Agent'),
        ('2017-11-01 05:07:18.702','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Client'),
        ('2017-11-01 05:07:43.128','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Agent'),
        ('2017-11-01 05:07:59.578','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Client'),
        ('2017-11-01 05:09:55.063','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Client'),
        ('2017-11-01 05:14:12.587','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Agent'),
        ('2017-11-01 05:14:56.369','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Client'),
        ('2017-11-01 06:06:56.108','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Agent'),
        ('2017-11-01 06:07:07.279','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Agent'),
        ('2017-11-01 06:21:17.548','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Client'),
        ('2017-11-01 06:21:38.428','C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E','Agent')



        SELECT 
tabC.whowritedmessage,
tabA.datemessage,
tabA.answer,
tabA.whowritedmessage,
tabA.id_tasks
FROM(SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY whowritedmessage ORDER BY datemessage) as number,
whowritedmessage
FROM #c1
where whowritedmessage ='Client') as tabC
join (SELECT 
              top 50 percent
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY whowritedmessage ORDER BY datemessage) as number,
LEAD(datemessage,7) OVER (ORDER BY whowritedmessage) as datemessage,
datemessage as answer,
whowritedmessage,
id_tasks
FROM #c1
) as tabA  on tabA.number = tabC.number
```

We have a table with data, you need to get the answer of the following from:

```
 Client 2017-11-01 04:59:07.6140000 2017-11-01 05:06:53.9090000 Agent C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
 Client 2017-11-01 05:07:18.7020000 2017-11-01 05:07:43.1280000 Agent C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
 Client 2017-11-01 05:07:59.5780000 2017-11-01 05:14:12.5870000 Agent C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
 Client 2017-11-01 05:14:56.3690000 2017-11-01 06:06:56.1080000 Agent C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
 Client 2017-11-01 06:21:17.5480000 2017-11-01 06:21:38.4280000 Agent C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
```

but I constantly get 7 lines, although there should be 5, because if the client goes the same next line, it is not taken into account and the same with the agent

Comment: Why does it need to be using RowNumber/Lead/Lag?

Comment: what is the expected ouput?

Comment: @KeithL if we have 
client
client
agent
client
agent

output: client-agent, client-agent

Comment: @TabAlleman this condition of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this script-

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
    LAG(whowritedmessage) OVER (ORDER BY datemessage) who_lag
    FROM #c1
)

SELECT whowritedmessage,
datemessage,
ans,
ISNULL(who_lag,'Agent') whowritedmessage2,
id_tasks 
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    LEAD(datemessage) OVER (ORDER BY datemessage) ans,
    LEAD(whowritedmessage) OVER (ORDER BY datemessage) who_lead
    FROM CTE
    WHERE (whowritedmessage <> who_lag OR who_lag IS NULL)
)A
WHERE whowritedmessage = 'Client'
```

Output is-

```
whowritedmessage    datemessage                 ans                          whowritedmessage2  id_tasks
Client              2017-11-01 04:59:07.6140000 2017-11-01 05:06:53.9090000  Agent              C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
Client              2017-11-01 05:07:18.7020000 2017-11-01 05:07:43.1280000  Agent              C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
Client              2017-11-01 05:07:59.5780000 2017-11-01 05:14:12.5870000  Agent              C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
Client              2017-11-01 05:14:56.3690000 2017-11-01 06:06:56.1080000  Agent              C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
Client              2017-11-01 06:21:17.5480000 2017-11-01 06:21:38.4280000  Agent              C56D5EF0-CBC4-473F-90A7-A7A10223AE3E
```

**Changed:**
For better understanding, I have added 1 more CTE here with same output as above script.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
    LAG(whowritedmessage) OVER (ORDER BY datemessage) who_lag
    FROM #c1
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  whowritedmessage,   datemessage,    
    LEAD(datemessage) OVER (ORDER BY datemessage) ans,
    ISNULL(who_lag,'Agent') whowritedmessage2,
    id_tasks
    FROM CTE
    WHERE (whowritedmessage <> who_lag OR who_lag IS NULL)
)

--SELECT * FROM CTE
--SELECT * FROM CTE2
SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE whowritedmessage = 'Client'
```

You can run one by one SELECT statement(Commented now) to understand how data is transforming step by step. Remember, 3rd SELECT statement is your final script and other 2 commented SELECT is just for your checking. Hope this will help you understand the whole process.

Comment: Thank you. I'm changed a little bit your code, and it is working. But i don't understand how)

Comment: :) nice to hear that it worked. But understanding of code is important for future purpose. You can let us know the part you are not getting fully.

Comment: I do not understand how you thought when solving this problem. With the first action, we use lag to shift the person who wrote the message, with the second action, we shift the time from the resulting table, because 4.59 time of the first request and it cannot be the first answer,
what's the second LEAD (whowritedmessage) over (order by datemessage) this_lead for?

Can you explain in words the algorithm of actions in solving this problem, please?

Comment: Actually I analyzed your input and output. I observed you kept first row if there consecutive rows with same "Whowritedmessage" value. That's why I used LAG to determine the previous value in CTE. Then I filter rows (2,4,8 & 12) with same value got from LAG. Rest part is just merging rows Client/Agent using LEAD function.

Comment: @Zeo I have added new codes to the answer. Hope this will help you understand the whole process.

Comment: Thank you very much again. Your answers really helped me understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.whowritedmessage,t2.datemessage,t2.answer,ISNULL(this_lag,'Agent') as whowritedmessage2,t2.id_tasks
FROM 
(SELECT *,
LEAD(datemessage) over (order by datemessage) answer,
LEAD(whowritedmessage) over (order by datemessage) this_lead
FROM
 (SELECT *,
LAG(whowritedmessage) over (order by datemessage) this_lag
FROM #c1) as t1
Where whowritedmessage <> this_lag or this_lag IS NULL) as t2
Where whowritedmessage = 'Client'
```